# How do I increment a specific number when I have two variables in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, subtraction

For my homework i'm supposed to use '*' to make a picture prescribed in the notes. Basically what I would like help with is how to use subtraction in a for loop.

My code:

```
public class Starshapesver2{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        star(31) ;
        System.out.println(); //I initialize 'star' and 'space' later on

        for(int i=1; i<=7; i=i+1){
            star(14);
            blank(5);
            star(14);
        }
        ...
```

basically how would I add 4 to 'blank' and subtract 4 from 'spaces' inside the for loop 
(and so that it would keep  adding on so the first blank would be 4 then 8 then 12 and so on)

sorry if this is confusing

Comment: `sorry if this is confusing` ,Yes it is.

Comment: `star` and `blank` aren't variables that you can add things to. They're methods. If you actually meant to declare variables, you'll need to change your code significantly.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ: Just as an aside, do you realize that using non-ASCII characters for your username, it's relatively hard to reply to you on SO? I don't know about anyone else, but I always have to copy and paste. If you just set your name to "Suresh Atta" (or still in all-caps if you really want) it would make life simpler for people trying to respond to comments.

Comment: @JonSkeet Since I can't add my self in comment's I haven't tried that and nobody inform me even about this. and I even seeing pictures  in names here on SO :) I hope @s gives my name to add in comment. Tested It's giving my name :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ why i dont have any hard time replying to you?? i just type @ then press `s` then tab then youre name already appears.

Comment: @JonSkeet how do you reply here in SO? arent you using the tab command?

Comment: @JonSkeet Here you go : http://imgh.us/stack_1.png .

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ can you teach me how to do that! hahaha :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: Hmm - it works now, but it hasn't in the past. Odd. I still think it would be "cleaner" to just use ASCII characters, but it's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 2):

are you expecting something like below

```
 for(int i=1,increment=4; i<=7; i=i+1,increment=increment+4)
        {
        star(14 - increment);
        blank(5 + increment);
        star(14 - increment);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to have the arguments you pass to star() and blank() change each time through the loop. So you need to make them variables. Declare them outside of the loop, and modify them with each pass. Something like this:

```
int numBlanks = 5;

for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    blanks(numBlanks);
    numBlanks = numBlanks + 4; // numBlanks will increase by 4 each time through the loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to continually add **4** to **blank** and subtract **4** from **Spaces** until the loop ends. Well you can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    star(31) ;System.out.println(); //I initialize 'star' and 'space' later on
    int Blankint = 5;
    int spacesint =4// i cannot see your spaces in the code
    for(int i=1; i<=7; i=i+1)
    {
        Star(14);
        blank(5+Blankint);
        Blankint =Blankint+4;
        spaces(20 - spacesint); //assuming this where your space is because you didnt indicated it above.
        spacesint = spacesint+4;
        star(14);
    }
}
```

With this code your blank increments evert loop adding 4 to blanks and subtracting 4 to spaces

So if your initial blank is 5 next would be 9 then after the loop it would be 13 etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean: "How would I add 4 to blank and substract 4 from spaces each iteration". At the same time assuming that these are methods which take an int.

```
for(int i=1; i<=7; i=i+1)
{
    star(14);
    //Make the call with the starting 5 adding i * 4 which varies each iteration
    blank(5 + i * 4);
    star(14);
}
```

You didn't show spaces in the loop itself but assuming it is there it could look like:

```
spaces(startingNumber - i * 4);
```